# How to stop overwriting data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to save some data in localStorage. but every time I refresh the page new data overwrite on older data and I lost my old data.

```
function testshod() {
    localStorage.setItem("hash", JSON.stringify(testblockchain));
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
    localStorage.getItem("hash");
    }
```

in store my data like this code. it works correctly but when I refresh the page data are gone.
p.s. testblockchain is a class.

Comment: Each time you refresh your page `testshod` function is called, that is why your data is overwritten. You can try and use `if` condition to check whether you already have some data in your `localStorage` and if `true` don't set it but only retrieve it instead.

Comment: check first if you already have something in localStorage and do write if localStorage is empty

Comment: which browser are you using? also you are not checking for data before writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if there is already a value in localStorage

```
function testshod() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("hash")) {
        localStorage.setItem("hash", JSON.stringify(testblockchain));
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("hash");
}
```

If you want to renew the hash after a given time you should also store the last updated time in the localStorage and check that too.